# How to make one URL redirect to another with the same URL path

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

So basically I have 2 domains, domain1.com and domain2.com

For domain2.com, I want to redirect it to domain1.com and keep the rest of the URL path intact.

For example:

`domain2.com/same/url/path` would redirect to
`domain1.com/same/url/path`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule in website root .htaccess of `domain2`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Couldn't have answered better myself, but I'm not sure about the `no escape` flag (NE). If the same CMS is used on the other domain it might break it.

Comment: No `NE` won't break anything. It might help for the cases when original URL contains some special characters

Comment: Exactly, and some special characters (you can refer to as html entities) might occur in GET requests and break if else statements. Peronaly I see no other use for this question unless it refers to the same system (presuming a CMS) with no further insight on its workings I said *might* not will.

Comment: As a follow up, would it be possible to do something like domain1.com/path/url redirecting to domain2.com/pathDurl where the / is replaced by a D or other character?

Comment: I can understand referring from your old or secondary domain to the main one, but not the other way around. At least up-vote if this answer works for you and ask a second one if needed.

Comment: As the @Xorifelse wrote please don't add a new question via comments. You cam mark this answer if this works and ask a new question for changing `/` to `D` letter

Comment: Sorry guys. Will do I just can't do the test right now.